# Unknown function: htmlcomplete#DetectOmniFlavor

Tags: vim, markdown

When I use vim to open one markdown file. i meet the following issue.
[image: screenshot for open error]

My Vim version is 7.4 and i use it on MacBook Pro with OS X Yosemite.

The following are the vim plugins i installed:
[image: vim plugins on my machine]

Anybody can help on this? many thanks:-)

---

### Adding runtimepath

[image: vim runtimepath]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this error after I installed the Vim plugin YouCompleteMe. After I updated my `html5.vim` Vim plugin the issue disappeared for me.

Comment: Hi @rednaw, i don't find the html5.vim in my installation of vim 7.4. do i need to install it manually?

Comment: Hi rednaw, i just updated my html5.vim plugin, it works now, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the `$VIMRUNTIME/autoload/htmlcomplete.vim` script; in your case, it should be at `/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.488/share/vim/vim74/autoload/htmlcomplete.vim`. If it really isn't there, try reinstalling Vim. Else, it might be a problem with your `'runtimepath'`.

**Edit**: It is the latter; your `'runtimepath'` has `~/.vim` twice, at the beginning and end, no *after* directories, and not the `.../share/vim/vim74` global one. Find our what messed up your `'runtimepath'`.

Comment: Hi Ingo, thanks for your response, i just checked /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.488/share/vim/vim74/autoload/, the htmlcomplete.vim is there.

Comment: By the way, i used “brew install vim --override-system-vim” to install vim 7.4

Comment: Does it help if you explicitly `:source` that file?

Comment: As your suggestion, we need :source that file every time, right?

Comment: It would be a workaround, but I would feel better finding and fixing the root cause. Does it work? Then, something's probably wrong with your `'runtimepath'` setting.

Comment: Thanks Ingo, it works, after :source, i open other markdown file, no errors. How do i check 'runtime path' setting?

Comment: `:set runtimepath?` should print a list that includes ` /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.488/share/vim/vim74`; if it doesn't, that's your problem. If it does, it looks like a dynamic problem, i.e. when you open the markdown file, it's somehow not there (or another problem).

Comment: Hi Ingo, i just added runtimepath in question. i copied https://github.com/Integralist/ProVim as my default .vim and .vimrc.

Comment: Hi Ingo, i just used @rednaw's solution to update my html5 plugin, and this issue has been resolved, thanks a lot, have a good one:-)

Comment: I'm glad you've found the problem.